# AndEngine: Moving a parallax background with the accelerometer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I want to move a parallax background (constant speed) when i tilt the phone. 
The parallax background is moving, but to slow and it flickers.
Maybe somebody has a good example or knows what's wrong?

Some parts of the code:

```
public class TestPhysicsActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity  implements IAccelerationListener{
...
 private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
 private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
 final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
 final ScrollableParallaxBackground background = new ScrollableParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, camera);
....    

  @Override  
  public void onLoadResources() {  
  this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);  
  }  

 ....
@Override
 public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
 }
 @Override
 public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
  final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
  this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
  Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
 background.setParallaxValue(this.mEngine.getSecondsElapsedTotal()*pAccelerationData.getX());

 }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For detecting phone tilting use orientation info (`onOrientationChanged`), not acceleration. This method will get `OrientationData` from which you can directly ask the tilt of the phone around each axis:

```
@Override public void onOrientationChanged(OrientationData pOrientationData) {
    pOrientationData.getYaw() //compass
    pOrientationData.getPitch() //one orientation axis
    pOrientationData.getRoll() //other orientation axis
}
```

Values returned by these methods are in degrees. I have implemented a full tilt-controlled game with information from only this method so I know it works just fine for that purpose.

Also remember to change the sensor enabling to use `enableOrientationSensor(this)` instead of the `enableAccelerationSensor`.

Comment: as far as I know , orientation info only detects if the device is in portrait/landscape mode .. could you elaborate more on that ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more complete, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this project here
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/moving-a-sprite-with-the-accelerometer-sensor-t1223.html

this one uses the accelerometer sensor to move a sprite , you can get an idea and change it so it affects the background for you, check the 2nd page in the forum where I posted a modified code that works on current versions of andEngine [that project doesn't use physics]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the data from mEngine.getSecondsElapsedTotal() is correct. From my experience, something fishy is going on with time tracking in AndEgine.